# This happened after I updated android studio No signature of method: android() is applicable for argument types. Exception in build.gradle (app)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Exception is:
Org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occured evaluating project ':app'. <149 internal lines>

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_e6q10tz3saa2h5agax22kff06.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_e6q10tz3saa2h5agax22kff06$_run_closure1) values: [build_e6q10tz3saa2h5agax22kff06$_run_closure1@60175043]
at build_e6q10tz3saa2h5agax22kff06.run(C:\users\me\ASP\myproject\app\build.gradle:3) <1 internal line>.... 148 more

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, i updated the gradle and the resulting deprecated compilersdk and sdkversiontool were causing this problem but it only showed once i updated the gradle again then it showed the deprication, my android studio was outdated i guess